# How to enable http response buffering on HaProxy?

Tags: haproxy

I hope I understand it right: HAProxy is able (http-mode) to
buffer the output (response) from a backend server, so that the
server process is made free as soon as possible. A slow client
would therefore "only" consume ressources on the HAProxy.
How much data from the response can be buffered by HAProxy?
Is there a config variable? Is it tcp/ip buffering or
buffering in HAProxy userspace?

Comment: our admin says that in situation "slow client -> haproxy-> backend" for http requests 
we have next behavior:
1) haproxy get request from client
2) then haproxy get fast response from backend
3) haproxy long returns a response to client. backend is free into this stage. 
But i not found description of this situation into HAProxy docs. If you have detailed answer to my question, i will happy to vote up your answer.
PS Sorry for my bad english